# How can I get this pivot kind of output in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle12c

Consider my source table as given below i.e customer.

How can i get the required output as shown using sql (oracle or mysql)

customer :

```
 customer id Purchase_id cashback 
 123        abc111          5
 123        abc112          5
 123        abc113          2
  345       abc311          0
 345        abc312          2   
 678        abc611          4   
 678        abc612          3   
 678        abc613          5
```

Output Needed:

```
 ID     purchare_id_1 purchare_id_2 purchare_id_3 cashback_1 cashback_2 cashback_3 
 123    abc111          abc112      abc113          5           5           2
 345    abc311          abc312                      0           2           
 678    abc611          abc612      abc613          4           3           5
```

DML and DDL:

```
create table cust_table (
customer_id int, Purchase_id varchar(100), cashback int
);

insert into cust_table values
 (123       , 'abc111'     ,     5),
 (123       , 'abc112'     ,     5),
 (123       , 'abc113'     ,     2),
 ( 345      , 'abc311'     ,     0),
 (345       , 'abc312'     ,     2),
 (678       , 'abc611'     ,     4),
 (678       , 'abc612'     ,     3),
 (678       , 'abc613'     ,     5);
 
 commit;
```

PS:
Data might be not static, it can change.

Comment: Select either Oracle or MySQL - this is 2 different DBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH
cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY Purchase_id) rn
         FROM cust_table )
SELECT customer_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Purchase_id END) purchase_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN Purchase_id END) purchase_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN Purchase_id END) purchase_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN cashback END) cashback_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN cashback END) cashback_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn=3 THEN cashback END) cashback_3
FROM cte
GROUP BY customer_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec2de721d7089a82a5f7ae669ce2d19e

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL: You can use `concat` along with `group by` to see partial result like as below

```
 select customer_id, group_concat(`Purchase_id` separator ',') as `Purchase_idX`,  
 group_concat(`cashback` separator ',') as `cashbackX` from cust_table 
 group by customer_id;
```

If you want the exact result run the below query:

```
 select 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(AA, ',', 1) as purchare_id_1,
    CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', AA, 2) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(AA, ',', 2), ',', -1)
    END AS purchare_id_2,
    CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', AA, LOCATE(',', AA, 1)+1) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(AA, ',', 3), ',', -1)
    END AS cashback_1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(BB, ',', 1) as purchare_id_1,
    CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', BB, 2) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BB, ',', 2), ',', -1)
    END AS cashback_2,
    CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(',', BB, LOCATE(',', BB, 1)+1) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(BB, ',', 3), ',', -1)
    END AS cashback_3 
 from 
 ( select customer_id, group_concat(`Purchase_id` separator ',') as AA,  group_concat(`cashback` separator ',') as BB,  
 group_concat(`cashback` separator ',') as `cashbackX` from cust_table 
 group by customer_id) as TB
```